# Code for Activating and Deactivating Audit Feature

Tags: ssom, spaudit

I am seeking for Server Object model to Activate and deactivate the SharePoint Audit Feature.

Can any one help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Adjust as needed.

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$auditmask = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::View -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Update `
    -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Delete -bxor [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditMaskType]::Search

$webapp.sites | % {

$_.TrimAuditLog = $true
$_.Audit.AuditFlags = $auditmask
$_.Audit.Update()
$_.AuditLogTrimmingRetention = 30
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
SPAudit audit = siteCollection.Audit;
audit.AuditFlags =
  SPAuditMaskType.SecurityChange |
  SPAuditMaskType.SchemaChange;
audit.Update();
```

For more information, please refer to the following link:

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/431342/auditing-a-built-in-feature-of-sharepoint
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/enable-auditing-sharepoint-b2bba327